# Returned array is unexpected

Tags: julia

The following lines

```
s = [1 2 5 7 3 3]
index=findall(x -> (x < 7 & x > 3), s)
[idx[2] for idx in index]
```

returns

```
0-element Array{Int64,1}
```

when there is a 5 in `s`. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Figured that `&` has to be replaced by `&&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` is bit-wise AND operator and the operator precedence kicks in here. The logical AND operator in Julia is `&&`.

You can use parenthesis to make your expression correct for your purpose, i.e. `(x > 7) & (x > 3)`, though I would not recommend this one.

You should instead use logical AND operator `&&`, or perhaps better directly write what you would write on a paper i.e. `3 < x < 7`. All of these methods work.

```
s = [1 2 5 7 3 3]
index=findall(x -> 3 < x < 7, s)
[idx[2] for idx in index]
```

Answer (score 3):

`&` operates on bits and the logical and is `&&`.

For what you want to do just use filter:

```
julia> filter(x -> 7 > x > 3, s)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 5
```